# Improve the execution time of a function which manage std::map objects, how?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, c++17

I have a header file `header.hpp` in which is declared this function:

```
#ifndef COMMON_HPP
#define COMMON_HPP

#include <string>
#include <map>

extern std::string func( const std::map <std::string, std::string>& generic_map, const std::string& feat_string )

#endif
```

and that function is defined in a `.cpp` file:

```
#include "header.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <map>

std::string func( const std::map <std::string, std::string>& map_s, const std::string& str )
 {
  if( map_s.find( str ) == map_s.end() ) 
   {
    throw std::runtime_error( "Error!" );
   }
  return map_s.at( str );
 }
```

Benchmarking registered an execution time of **292 ns** in 2684415 iterations. Do you know if there is any way to improve the function in order to make it faster?

Comment: Did you measure this with elements found all the time, or were there cases when it was not found?

Comment: If the code works, and you just want to optimize it, then this question belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: `find` returns an iterator to the string. Why do you search for it again with `at` instead of remembering what you `find`?

Comment: @lorro only with the cases with elements found

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah in a certain sense it works, but not as I want since it too slow for my requirements

Comment: @GianlucaBianco That's what Remy hinted about. Working code that you want to improve is probably better posted at _Codereview_.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco The code works if it exhibits the correct behavior, which yours does. Optimizing its speed is a separate issue, and is an art of its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given how small the code is, there is really not many changes you  can make to it, but there are a few:

- use the `iterator` that `map::find()` returns, you don't need to call `map::at()` afterwards. You are actually performing the same search 2 times, when you really want to perform it only 1 time.
- return a reference to the found value, to avoid making a copy of it (`map::at()` returns a reference anyway).  The exception you are throwing will ensure the returned reference is never invalid.
- If you don't need the `map` to be sorted, use `std::unordered_map` instead, which is *usually* faster than `std::map` for inserts and lookups.

Try this:

```
const std::string& func( const std::map <std::string, std::string>& map_s, const std::string& str )
{
    auto iter = map_s.find( str );
    if (iter == map_s.end() ) 
        throw std::runtime_error( "Error!" );
    return iter->second;
}
```

That being said, if you don't mind what kind of error message is thrown, you can replace `map::find()` with `map::at()`, since `map::at()` throws its own `std::out_of_range` exception if the key is not found (that is the whole purpose of `map::at()` vs `map::operator[]`), eg:

```
const std::string& func( const std::map <std::string, std::string>& map_s, const std::string& str )
{
  return map_s.at( str );
}
```

Comment: I like the answer, but a quick note on `std::unordered_map`: it's not guaranteed to finish under O(N) time. Usually, it's O(1), but if you're unlucky, it might be slow for some inputs. So, for real-time systems where each query must finish within given time (in contrast to normal use cases where average/amortized runtime is important), it's not recommended to use it. For average case, non-realtime, it's still very performant and useful.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing two lookups into the map to get the element you seek:

Here's an immediate improvement:

```
std::string func( const std::map <std::string, std::string>& map_s, const std::string& str )
 {
    auto itor = map_s.find(str);
    if (itor == map_s.end())
    {
      throw std::runtime_error( "Error!" );
    }
    return itor->second;
 }
```

The other improvement you can make is to use a [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead of `std::map`. If you don't need to enumerate keys in the map in any sorted or consistent order, you should use unordered_map, which is O(1) for insertion and lookup.  The ordered map will likely have O(lg N) runtime for insertion and lookup.  (i.e. hash table vs binary tree implementations for the collections).  `std::unordered_map` and `std::map` have near identical interfaces, so it's an easy drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 2):

First, it returns `std::string` instead of `const std::string&`, which is slow (involves a copy).

Also, exceptions in current compilers are very expensive. A possible way around them is to return a `const std::string*` and return `nullptr` in case element is not found (also removed double lookup):

```
const std::string* func( const std::map <std::string, std::string>& map_s, const std::string& str )
 {
  auto it = map_s.find( str );
  if( it == map_s.end() ) 
   {
    return nullptr;
   }
  return &(it->second);
 }
```

An advanced technique is continuation passing style, which can further optimize your code (and save you a branching). In this case, instead of returning something, you pass what should be done with the result:

```
template<typename Found, typename NotFound>
void func( const std::map <std::string, std::string>& map_s, const std::string& str Found found, NotFound notFound)
{
  auto it = map_s.find( str );
  if( it == map_s.end() ) 
  {
    return notFound();
  }
  return found(it->second);
}
```

Usage:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
std::string s;
func(m, s, [&](const std::string& elem) {
  /* found - do something with elem */
}, [&]() {
  /* not found - error handler */
});
```

This is like if you had your own control structures. Of course, you could make the return type different from void (in case you'd like to 'tunnel' the result of `found(elem)` and `notFound()`). If you'd like, you can share e.g. the error handler among multiple calls to the function (in which case, you store it in a variable, like `const auto onNotFound = [&]() { /* ... */ };`). Of course, when you're optimizing, you might limit the capture of the lambda to what's necessary.

Comment: @lorro Why * and not & in the return type?

Comment: The only downside to this approach is that it requires the caller to be responsible for handling the pointer correctly and not dereference it if `nullptr` is returned. Which can easily be overlooked if the caller is not careful. Perhaps consider returning `std::optional<std::string>` instead

Comment: @GianlucaBianco because this function is returning a *pointer* not a *reference*

Comment: @GianlucaBianco So you can `return nullptr` in the case the element is not found (instead of throwing an exception). Another possibility is passing two lambdas of what to do with it: `template<typename Found, typename NotFound>` func(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& map_s, const std::string& str, Found found, NotFound notFound)` which would call either `found(elem)` (elem being `const std::string&)` or `notFound()`.

Comment: @lorro could you please add another example with this latest statement to your question? Thanks (I am evaluating the best answer right now)

Comment: @GianlucaBianco I wouldn't go the lambda approach, that just makes the code more complicated, and has more overhead in creating and managing the lambdas, especially if they are stateful (capturing variables).

Comment: At the moment, code complexity is not a problem for me. The only important thing is speed performance

Comment: @GianlucaBianco Added that as well to this answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It avoids _additional_ branching in the calling code (since you pass the branches). Also, it can reuse the error handlers. Normally, compiler optimizes lambdas completely, so the creating objects part shouldn't be an issue (this is not theoretically, but based on code generators that I wrote and that used lambdas extensively, recursively, many-many levels - no issues to gcc).